# Manipulating expression $(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$ in inductive step.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

My question concerns the inductive step of the proof below. I've typed out the work I've done so far. If anyone has any suggestions on how to proceed thanks in advance.

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{4})(1-\frac{1}{8})(1-\frac{1}{16})\cdots(1-\frac{1}{2^n})\ge\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

$Proof.$ We use mathematical induction.

*Base Case.* For $n=1$ we see that $1-\frac{1}{2}\ge\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$ since $\frac{1}{2}\ge\frac{1}{2}$.

*Inductive Step*. Let $n>1$. Assume our statement is true for $n$. Now observe that

$\begin{align}(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{4})(1-\frac{1}{8})(1-\frac{1}{16})\cdots(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})&\ge\\
\left((1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{4})(1-\frac{1}{8})(1-\frac{1}{16})\cdots(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}})\right)(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})&\ge(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})
\end{align}$

My question is: How do we get from
$\begin{align}
(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})
\end{align}$ to $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)+1}}$?

Most of what I've attempted has led to tedious calculations that do not simplify to the desired result. I've also tried making the argument that $(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$ must be $\ge$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ but then I'm stuck with $\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)+1}}$... Is my approach incorrect here?

Comment: In your inductive step, why do you have a hypothesis of equality, where inequality should be?
This may also explain your main difficulty - you do not have to prove equality, only inequality.

Comment: @AndrisBirkmanis Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Comment: you are almost there.  Show that $(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}) >\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$ and you are done.  Multiply it out.  The algebra is not so tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: How do we get from
>   $\begin{align}
> (\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})
> \end{align}$ to $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)+1}}$?

Note that we have to show that
$$\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\color{red}{\ge}\frac 14+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$$

One has 
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)&= \frac 14-\frac{1}{2^{n+3}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}\\&= \frac 14+\frac{-2^{n-1}+2^{n+1}-1}{2^{2n+2}}\\&=\frac 14+\frac{3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1}{2^{2n+2}}\\&= \frac 14+\frac{2^n+(2^{n-1}-1)}{2^{2n+2}}\\&\color{red}{\ge}\frac 14+\frac{2^n+0}{2^{2n+2}}\\&=\frac 14+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\end{align}$$

Comment: is the three in the third step a typo?

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon: No, we have $-2^{n-1}+2^{n+1}=2^{n-1}(-1+2^2)=3\cdot 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon: I'll add some details. After the step, we have that $3\cdot 2^{n-1}=(2+1)\cdot 2^{n-1}=2\cdot 2^{n-1}+1\cdot 2^{n-1}=2^n+2^{n-1}$ and that $2^{n-1}-1\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have to show that
$$(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})\geq \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)+1}}$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+3}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}\geq \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+3}}-\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}\geq \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}.$$
Now multiply both sides by $2^{n+3}$,
$$4-1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\geq 2$$
or
$$ 1\geq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$
which holds.