# Demonstration by inducing slightly different inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction, natural-numbers

We know the following inequality,

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)\geq\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

We can find in these links the demonstration for induction of this result: [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3894217/prove-by-induction-left1-frac12-right-ldots-left1-frac12n-righ), [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929391/manipulating-expression-frac14-frac12n11-frac12n1-i) and [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714479/if-n-in-mathbbn-then-1-1-2-1-1-41-1-81-1-16-1-1-2n-geq-1-41).

Obviously the result is still true if we change the right side by,

$$\frac{1}{4}\color{red}{-}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

Of course, I could use the previous inequality to complete this one, but I would like to know if it is possible to prove it directly by induction. It all comes down to proving this inequality,

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\ge\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$$

That it is not true, then, does that mean that it is not possible to show by induction? In this case, how would this result be demonstrated?

Comment: The last inequality is not true eg when $n=1$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Now it's right

Comment: @M no try $n=1$ again!!

Comment: Truth! I was using a wrong value. So it's probably not possible to do it by induction ....

Comment: @Mrcrg The LHS of the bottom inequality should be $$\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4} \color{red}{+} \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}}\right)$$ See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929391/manipulating-expression-frac14-frac12n11-frac12n1-i

Comment: @光復香港時代革命FreeHongKong I'm not talking about the original inequality, it is still true if the signal changes.

Comment: @Mrcrg If you switch signs on both LHS and RHS, the inequality switches direction: $$\begin{align}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right) \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)
&= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{2^{n+3}} + \frac{1}{2^{2n+2}} \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\right) - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} - \frac{1}{2^{n+3}} + \frac{1}{2^{2n+2}} \\ &\le \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\right) - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} + \frac{1}{2^{2n+2}} \\ &\le \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\end{align}$$ since $\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}} - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} \le 0$ by induction.

Comment: You likely cannot prove it directly by induction since the LHS is multiplied by a term that is < 1 but the RHS increases (is multiplied by a term that is > 1). If given this version, I would have done a "stronger inequality" which was the original version.